# How to get both parent and child samples in Jmeter specifically for Parallel Controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am working on a use case where I have to hit multiple API end-points in parallel. I need to capture the response time of all the end-points and also the highest response time. By checking the Generate parent sample for Parallel controller I am getting the highest response time but then I am not getting the response time for child samples(all end-points). If I don't check the Generate parent sample then only the response time of end-points I am able to see in report and not the highest response time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're talking about, if I add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener I'm able to see both highest and individual response times:

[image]

The same applies to [JMeter test execution in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/), the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) contains 3 entries: individual response times and the highest one:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1645003103393,1916,bzm - Parallel Controller,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,,true,,14450,351,1,1,null,0,0,0
1645003103597,593,example.com,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1046,113,1,1,http://example.com/,585,0,435
1645003103597,1712,jmeter.apache.org,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,13404,238,1,1,https://jmeter.apache.org/,764,0,435
```

Comment: Yes in the view results tree we can see the child samples. If I save the result in jtl then also I can see the child samples by reading the jtl with a listener.  But I want this to appear in the report (Aggregate report listener) and in my case I have to run it from Blazemeter. In Blazemeter request stats, only the bzm-Parallel Controller is coming.

Comment: Downloaded the jtl file (kpi.jtl) for Blazemeter execution and opened it with aggregate report listener. It also giving only the parent sample(bzm-Parallel Controller).

Comment: Man, you have `jmeter` in tags and now you're asking about BlazeMeter and [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation). By default [Taurus doesn't save subresults](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#CSV-file-content-configuration) and it can be amended using config files or `-o` command-line argument. For BlazeMeter related questions I think you need to contact ]BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)